# Howto put a character in superscripts in a table celll in python docx

Tags: python, docx

I want to put the text 'm/s2' in a table cell. How to get the '2' in superscript?

Comment: Can I use a add_run() to cell.text?

Answer (score 1):

You need run text in table cell

```
run_table_row1_cell2 = table_row1_cell2.paragraphs[0].add_run('hello')
run_table_row1_cell2.font.subscript = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Unicode value of ².

Use a Unicode string:

```
u"m/s\u00B2"
```